# Opening a list of installed chat applications in "complete action using" in android

Tags: android, onclicklistener

Following code opens sms applications But I want to open system installed chat application list such as viber, whatsapp etc.

Please help to correct this code.

```
//setting onclicklistner to chat button
        chat_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"+TelNos[position]));
                    context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Create intent choose as follows.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    ...


    // Create intent to show chooser
    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "title");

    // Verify the intent will resolve to at least one activity
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(chooser);
    }
```

For more details http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html

Comment: where you are accessing getPackageManager , in fragment or activity?

Comment: if you are in activity and accessing getPackageManager in onClick method then use YourActivity.this.getPackageManager()

Comment: I used `context.getPackageManager()` It sloves the problem. But there is no apps listing(I have viber,whatsapp in the phone).

Answer (score 0):

For Any application you can open using their specific package name,
for ex.
You need to know Skype using its package name (something like: com.skype.android), then you can start it:

`PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
 startActivity(packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.skype.android"));`

same thing for all other application.

Comment: Is there any method to open list of available chat applications on the device when the button click.